# Is it always true for vector and matrix multiplication?

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus

I have seen that $$\frac{\partial \textbf{x}^T\textbf{B}\textbf{x}}{\partial \textbf{x}}=\textbf{x}^T(\textbf{B}+\textbf{B}^T)$$ and also $$\frac{\partial \textbf{x}^T\textbf{B}\textbf{x}}{\partial \textbf{x}}=(\textbf{B}+\textbf{B}^T)\textbf{x}$$ which suggests that $\textbf{x}^T\textbf{C}=\textbf{Cx}$? Is it always true where $\textbf{C=B+B}^T$? Any help in this regard will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are two different convention.  The first equation is the row convention and the second equation is the column convention. We shouldn't use two convention simultaenously.

$x^TC$ is a row vector while $Cx$ is a column vector. They can't be equal.

Comment: thank you for your comment. Do you mean that in the first equation $\textbf{x}$ is a row vector and for the second equation $\textbf{x}$ is a column vector?

Comment: i am assuming $B$ to be square matrix

Comment: Or do you mean that the gradient is actually the row vector in first equation while it is represented by a column vector in the second equation?

Comment: For both equations, $x$ is a column vector. The output of $\frac{\partial x^TBx}{\partial x}$ is a vector. You are the boss with $2$ secretaries, you read out your result which is $1,2,3$, the first secretary write down the result in a horizontal line while the second write it vertically.... hence two convention.

Answer (score 0):

Do not confuse. Different authors have proposed different definitions for derivative of a scalar relative to a vector. indeed you have considered two different definitions equal.If you see H.Khalil book of nonlinear control he has used the first and F.Lewis in optimal control has used the second.Logically you can not take two different definitions of a same things equal. It is better to put a triangleover the equal sign